# In python How to execute hadoop commands after changing the user to SU?

Tags: python, shell, hadoop

I am trying to copy data from one node to another node using python script.

I executed below command to copy the data from one node to other node in shell.

```
$sudo su hd

bash-4.1$hadoop distc hdfs://namenode-104/test104/  hdfs://namenode-103/test103/
```

I am able to copy the data.

When I am trying to implement same in python, I am not able to copy the data it is Hanging.

Below code I have tried:

```
 import sys
    import commands as com
    com.getoutput('sudo su hd')
    com.getoutput('hadoop distc hdfs://namenode-104/test104/  hdfs://namenode-103/test103/')
    print("Done")
```

how can I execute above 2 commands using python script.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't run `sudo su` as python

Make python script just run using `sudo su - hd -c 'python script.py'`